# Xubuntu 18.04 External Monitor not detected via HDMI

Tags: sound, hdmi, amd-graphics, monitor

I'll preface by saying that I'm a linux newbie, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Running Xubuntu 18.04, no dual boot. Monitor works fine on other PCs.

xrandr output with monitor plugged in:

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1366 x 768, current 1366 x 768, maximum 1366 x 768
default connected 1366x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1366x768      76.00*

aplay -l output, also with monitor plugged in:

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

lspci | grep VGA output:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M]

lspci | grep HDMI output: 01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500/6600 / 6700M Series]

I've tried solutions provided on other threads and forums, but to no avail. I've also tried switching b/w Lightdm and gdm3, same result.
Please let me know if any further details are required. Thanks in advance.